# Parse the xml and add the tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the below input xml and need to read the values under the  tag where class attribute is equal to ss_form_columns. And need to place the  after reading 32 characters.

Input XML is :

```
<html>
<div class="SS_Form_Columns">

                        <span class="SS_LeftAlign"> City of <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/>, City of <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Police Department, County of <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/>, County of <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Sheriff’s Department, <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Channel, Inc., <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Film Co., <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> and <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/>, </span>

</div>
    </html>
```

I am getting is below out put :

```
<div class="SS_Form_Columns">

                         City of , City<br_tag></br_tag>of  Police Department, County of<br_tag></br_tag>, County of  Sheriff’s<br_tag></br_tag>Department,  Channel, Inc.,  Film<br_tag></br_tag>Co.,  and , 

</div>
```

Required out put is :

```
<html>
 <div class="SS_Form_Columns">

                        <span class="SS_LeftAlign"> City of <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/>, City of <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Police<br_tag></br_tag> Department, County of<br_tag></br_tag> <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/>, County of <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Sheriff’s Department, <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Channel,<br_tag></br_tag> Inc., <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> Film Co., <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/> and <span class="SS_Form_Input SS_Form_DotBorder" style="width:11em"/>, </span>

     </div>
    </html>
```

My code is below :

```
 namespace BrTag
 {
  class Program
  {
    static int formTitleLength = 32;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"D:\Srinivas\BrTag\XMLFile1.xml";

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader("D:\\Srinivas\\BrTag\\XMLFile12.xml"), LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants())
        {
            if (element.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == "div") //looking for the footnote text
            {
                try
                {
                    if (element.Attribute("class") != null)

                        if (element.Attribute("class").Value.ToLower() == "ss_form_columns")
                        {
                            XElement elem = element;


                            if (elem.Value.Length > formTitleLength)
                            {
                                int cntr = 0;
                                string value = "";
                                ArrayList obj = new ArrayList();
                                string[] words = elem.Value.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

                                foreach (string word in words)
                                {
                                    if ((cntr + word.Length) > formTitleLength)
                                    {
                                        //add the current line of the title to the collection
                                        obj.Add(value);
                                        //create the br_tag element and add it to the collection
                                        XElement brTag = new XElement("br_tag", "");
                                        brTag.Name = XNamespace.None.GetName(brTag.Name.LocalName);
                                        obj.Add(brTag);
                                        //start the next line of the title string
                                        value = word;
                                        cntr = word.Length;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (cntr == 0)
                                        {
                                            value = word;
                                            cntr += word.Length;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            value += string.Format(" {0}", word);
                                            cntr += word.Length + 1; //add 1 to account for space
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                obj.Add(value);
                                //use the collection of ojects, title string and br_tag elements, to create a replacement element
                                XElement ne = new XElement(elem.Name, new XElement(elem.Name, obj.ToArray()),
                                from a in elem.Attributes() select a);
                                elem.ReplaceWith(ne);

                            }
                            element.ReplaceWith(elem);
                            //Console.WriteLine(elem);
                        }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

                }

            }

        }




    }
   }
 }
```

Any one could you please help on this.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I am able to read the values and replacing the values after 32 character but after that am unable to added the required charecter into that output.
elem.Replacewith(ne); is not working properly getting exception.

Comment: After did the elem.ReplaceWith(ne); operation I excepted the required output but I am getting different output results.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replace ?

Comment: Read the content values in the DIV tag, and replace the with <br_tag> after every >32 character of the content.
If you observer the input and required out put xml, You can find some <br_tag> added in the output.

Ex :
Input XML have : "Police Department"
Output XML have : "Police<br_tag></br_tag> Department"

Comment: Need to break the line after 32 characters. In my document two columns are there so if not breaking after 32 characters first column text overlap with second column text.
Could you please help on this?

Comment: You should probably just work on word-wrapping inside the document and not editing the source to introduce line breaks arbitrarily.

Comment: Actually it is one of the sample div tag in my entaire xml.
String we can wrap, how we can wrap the this senario?